# Do i still need the insulation in an old ceiling light if I'm no longer using incandescent bulbs?

Tags: light-fixture

The insulation itself is in fairly ragged shape after I pulled it down and then replaced it. (I wanted to avoid it getting soaked due to a plumbing leak above.)

[image]

In addition to being in poor shape, when I went to reinstall the light bulbs I'd removed when I pulled the insulation down I noticed that both appeared to have suffered damage from overheating, presumably due to being in direct contact with the insulation.

[image]

Am I safe in assuming the insulation was only needed originally because incandescent bulbs put out much larger quantities of heat, and that it is no longer needed with modern low power bulbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as it's possible to screw an incandescent in there, someone will.  So the insulation must stay, otherwise you are using the product inconsistent with its labeling or instructions, voiding its UL listing by altering it, all of which is a codevio.

The CFLs overheated because they were in a confined closed fixture, the insulation had nothing to do with it.  *Been there, done that.*  The root problem is you were using CFLs somewhere they should not be used, such as *2017.*

That is your basic "tenant grade cheapie" fixture, and if you're absolutely in mad love with it, I would look for some ~8 watt LED screw-ins to put in there, might still have overheating problems though.

If money is no object, get a nice soldered-in-LEDs fixture where the LEDs and their heat sink are integral to the fixture, *and which aims the LED light properly*.  Almost everyone wants a cone of light, and fixtures try to give it to you with inefficient reflectors.   LED screw-ins don't avoid that, they corncob them around to try to light a sphere.  But purpose built fixtures can be aimed or even lensed.

Comment: It always intrigued me how people talked about how wonderful CFL's were energy wise. When the reality of it is, they didn't save all that much especially since they typically lasted no longer than their incandescent cousins. Not to mention, while the BULB may not throw much heat, the ballast sure do :)  now I say all of that with one main tenat in mind, the RUSH to produce cheap CFl's gave us the equivalent of an incadescent at a higher cost and a much larger environment impact. SIGH.

Comment: They were ok for the 90s, and they were more efficient. Build quality super matters and I learned to avoid certain brands.  After that I stopped having a high failure rate, but now I have the problem of boxes of the things that are too good to toss.

Comment: You actually found good ones? I did have some good luck, but like I said, I had to find quality units. I never had one last 10 years. More expensive to manufacture, more troublesome to use, more troublesome to dispose of, and more impact to the environment. I do not believe that they ever were more efficient in any decade all things considered. I totally agree with going LED based. Still expensive to make LED's price and quality will both teeter. I'd honestly like to see a comparison of CFL vs incandescent from cradle to grave. I suspect its eye opening. (pun intended)

Comment: Ohhh... just found this.... not sure I buy it yet, but still:  http://www.thewatt.com/?q=node/175  The main thing is the insistent # of years a CFL will last. and how short of a life is suggested for incandescent. It throws the #'s off in the end. Interesting read on the 1.7 vs 0.3 to produce. I'll have to read the rest.

Comment: Yeah, gotta be cautious of those, I mean some say a Prius is less efficient than an Expedition and that solar is a total lose for climate change.  It gets so political so fast.

Comment: Most definitely. The real impact that people ignore is economy of scale. And of course, over time, investment in scale brings economy. I just am pointing out the disregard people have with respect to CFLs' because they see it as a cost from their pocket than a cost overall.Clearly your answer is spot on, and your recommendation is solid. Its just unfortunate that LED tech is still expensive on the pocket, but at least the technology is attainable such that lifespan can be truly significant. Now they just need to provide serviceable LED bulbs where you replace a "fuse" (CCA) vs. the entire assy

Comment: You're right about the fixture being a landlord special.  It's ugly as sin, and something I'm not permitted to replace.  I'm still using CFLs everywhere because they were cheaper in big economy packs and I've never had problems getting something like the rated number of hours from them.

Comment: Looking on Amazon, it seems the only LED bulbs claiming to be rated for fully enclosed are almost exclusively from companies I've never heard of and am presuming are no-name Chinese junk whose claims aren't trustworthy.  The only exception I've seen are significantly dimmer (40W equivalent) and higher temperature (5000K) than I need and want.

Comment: You're not permitted to tear the insulation off and shred it either, so that rule's done and broked.  As a landlord I would expect you to report the fixture as defective so it could be replaced.  I wouldn't care if you didn't go so far as to mentioning why it was shredded. Fair chance you're in a district where the law requires him to install efficient lighting.  If not, your *worst* case is you're back to *status quo ante* without the insulation falling down on the "bulb".  Or you might get luckier and get a vented fixture.

Comment: Having shopped a lot for LEDs, you aren't trying very hard. That fixture is closed, not sealed, and the key to that is thermal management. The "bulbs" need to be cooler than 55C or so to work decently. Even with LEDs, essentially all its wattage turns to heat, so the key is look for the most efficient bulbs you can get.  Alternately, you could just *leave the dome off*, it only needs to be on there when you move out, and you'll take your bulbs with you and leave a couple of 40W incandescents.

Comment: I'm in the back of beyond, there's no effective regulation beyond vermin control.  From past interactions with him; nothing short of it failing to operate at all is going to get it replaced and if it is the replacement will almost certainly be another bulb holding fixture because it would be the cheapest junk he could find.

Comment: And since my Amazon-fu continues to fail me, what is the middle grade of LED bulbs I should be searching for if basic ones might overheat but I don't need ones rated for fully enclosed fixtures either.  The only intermediate grade I've seen is some flood style bulbs that say they're ok in open bottom ceiling cans; but those are completely unstable for the fixture I've got.

Comment: I go with Cree, a great newcomer, or the old Phoebus cartel: GE, Osram/Sylvania, Philips.  The old cartel is actually bailing out of the business, not seeing a future in 25 year lamps, which is ironic given what the cartel was about.  GE is the only one still really in it, and Cree of course.  Get the Energy Star  1.1 (25,000 hr) ones.  I had great luck at Target with GE ones for about $3 each.